Help with Stopping Positions of Games
In On Numbers and Games by Conway, in the section on stopping positions, he says that we stop a game once it reaches a number. For a game/position $G$, $P(G)$ is defined to be player $P$ playing on position $G$.
Then, as an example, he looks at $G=\{\{3|0\}|\{\frac{1}{2}|9\}\}$. He says that, if Right starts, the stopping position is $R(\frac{1}{2})$. But, if Right starts, once we get to $\{\frac{1}{2}|9\}$, we would have stopped already, since $\{\frac{1}{2}|9\}=1$, so the stopping position would be $L(1)$, right? Because he says "We can be kind to the players and agree to stop the game (possibly before its real end) as soon as the value becomes a number..." (my emphasis in bold).
He also says in the paragraph after that one that "Left will naturally prefer to arrange that when the game stops in this sense, its value will be as large as possible...", so why would Left want to play $\frac{1}{2}$ since that move only decreases the value?
In this case, it ends up not mattering since $G$ is just $0$ in both cases, but if instead $G=\{\{3|1\}|\{\frac{1}{2}|9\}\}$, depending on if we choose $R(G)=L(1)$ or $R(G)=R(\frac{1}{2})$, we can end up with either $\{x\in\textbf{No}:x<1\}<G<1, G||1$ or $\frac{1}{2}<G<1$ where $G$ is confused with all numbers between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$, inclusive (unless I've made an error, which is very likely)
Is this just an error in the book? Like he maybe forgot $\{\frac{1}{2}|9\}=1$?

I would have thought $R(\frac12)$ was equal to $R({0|1})$ and so equal to $1$ and to $L(1)$.

I think it's just an error in the book.

@Henry: $R\left(\frac12\right)$ is just $\frac12$ since $\frac12$ is a number.

You are correct, it is most probably a typo. A simple fix like changing $9$ to $-9$ makes it make sense, so maybe he missed a sign.
